# Quick serialize SQL data into python list

Tags: python, postgresql, serialization

I have a Postgresql database with two tables:
(1) users
(2) user_entries

This is normalized such that I have a one to many relationship between users and user_entries. For example, an entry in users will have

```
id=0, email=user@email.com, name=Alice Mcbob
```

And then I can have two entries in user_entries:

```
id=0, user_id=0, major=english, class='lit101'
id=1, user_id=0, major=english, class='science101'
id=2, user_id=0, major=science, class='lit101'
```

this would be a student with 2 majors and I can key based on either one.

I have some python code and I'm trying to return a list of users (as object), each of whom has a list of classes. For example, I want to return:

```
[
  {
      'email': 'user@user.com,
      'name': 'Alice McBob',
      'classes': [
         'lit101',
         'science101'
      ],
  },
     'email': ...
   ...
]
```

My current strategy involves doing a fetchall() where I grab every user and inner join it with every class, and then I create a unique identifier for each user such that I can do `user_id-major` and I can determine which one I'm looking for. Then, I have a list of identifiers that I keep track of. And I go through each entry, find out if I've seen it before (check to see if the identifier exists). If I have, add the class to that persons list of classes. Otherwise, make a new list of classes.

However, this is super duper not performant. I have only 500 users and doing this takes about 15 seconds. As this is an api where I'm constantly doing the get, this is really not ideal. Also, the code feels extremely clunky as duplicates are an issue.

I have two functions:

```
def get_full_list(conn=None):
    user_list = []
    prev_checklist = []
    query = """
        SELECT id, email, name, major, class FROM 
            users
            INNER JOIN user_entries
            ON users.id=user_entries.user_id 
    """
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(query)
        for row in cur.fetchall():
            identifier = str(row[0]) + '-' + str(row[3])
            user = return_user_from_row(identifier, user_list, prev_checklist, row)
            user_list.append(user)
conn.commit()
return json.dumps(user_list)

def return_user_from_row(identifier="", user_list=[], prev_checklist=[], row=None):
    if identifier in prev_checklist:
        index = prev_checklist.index(identifier)
        user = user_list[index]
        user_classes = user['class']
        user_classes.append(str(row[4])
        user['class'] = user_classes
        user_list[index] = user
    else: 
        prev_checklist.append(identifier)
        user = {
            'email': '' if row[1] == None else row[1],
            'name': '' if row[2] == None else row[2],
            'major': '' if row[3] == None else row[3],
            'class': [''] if row[4] == None else [row[4]],
        }
    return user
```

Is there an easier and more performant version of this where I utilize the SQL command itself to do a lot of this for me? Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Please provide your code, where you try to achieve result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a SQL query to do *all* of this. Try:

```sql
select json_agg(json_build_object
(
 'email', u.email, 
 'name', u.name, 
 'classes', (select json_agg(distinct class) from user_entries ue where ue.user_id = u.id)
))
from users u;
```

There are other ways to write the same query too (using `cross join lateral` for example). I think that this one is easy to read.